# showing the ten post thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show latest  ten post of my security category with date and post title and the post thumbnail.
To show the pic I have faced with problem. According to this article

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-featured-image-or-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/
when we want to showing the thumbnail first of all we should have to copy the following code to the function.php file

```
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

and using the

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

To show pic of the post, I use this code into the loop but it doesn’t work. my code is here:

```
    <?php query_posts('securitysoft=CATEGORYNAME&showposts=10');
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>  
        <br/>

    <?php 
        php the_post_thumbnail(); 
?>
       <br/>
       <?php the_time(__('j/F/ Y','kubrick')) ?>
        <br/>
        <?php the_title();?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The main problem is that the picture does not show. To prove this I am taking post Id of the post that has thumbnail(292) like this :

```
       <?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail(292))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yes')</script>";
            has_post_thumbnail(292);
    }
        else
        {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('no')</script>";
                        has_post_thumbnail(292);
        }
```

?>
note:292 is the post id
The result of above code is no.
I have replaced php the_post_thumbnail(); with each one of following code but does not work:

```
  get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

  get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');

  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');

  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
```

And this is my function.php :

```
<?php
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

      if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
           register_sidebar();
?>
```

Comment: change securitysoft=CATEGORYNAME  to category_name=securitysoft in your post argument where securitysoft to change your category name thanks,

Comment: the problem is not with categoryname(i changed right now to what you said) because the result of the loop is right and i get the post title but the only problem is the thumbnail. thanks

Comment: changing to this but doesnt works query_posts('securitysoft=category_name&showposts=10');

Comment: query_posts('category_name=securitysoft&showposts=10');

Answer (score 0):

do you set the feature image!! remember if you don't set the feature image. the image won't display. because this command that you have used only take the thumbnail. to set the feature image go to the feature image panel and click on the Set featured image link.

Comment: thank you its work i haven't set the feature image. thank you